# Get Keycloak auth-server-url from request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, keycloak

I want to create dynamic links to the profile and logout url:

```
 scheme://servername:port/auth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/logout
 scheme://servername:port/auth/realms/realmname/account
```

When using OIDC in the keycloak.json of the java-ee project the auth-server-url is stated:

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "scheme://servername:port/auth",
  ...
}
```

Is there something like

```
request.getAuthServerUrl();
```

available to get

```
 auth-server-url
```

programmatically in Java from the request?

Would be nice, if i don't have to read from the file itself manually.

The keycloak.json must have already been read from by the application so this information might be available as an attribute of a Keycloak object.

Comment: If you dont want to read it from `keycloak.json` then its ok to read from properties file for you ?

Comment: i clarified my question in an edit; i do not want to read from the same file which keycloak must have already read from to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself:

```
 var principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
 String issuer = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getIssuer();
```

issuer now contains the desired url.

It is not actually the value which is stated in the keycloak.json, it is of the form

```
 scheme://server:port/auth/realms/realmname
```